# Why is the result here -40?

Tags: javascript

**Snippet 1**

```js
function a(x,y){
    console.log(x-y);
}

a("10","40");
```

**Snippet 2**

```js
function a(x,y){
    console.log(x+y);
}

a("10","40");
```

The output in the second is 1040, so why the first one is -40 even if the arguments are strings?

Comment: subtraction coerces to number, because there's no subtracting strings.

Comment: Because the `+` operator is overloaded for strings in the form of concatenation. Also, shouldn't it be `-30`?

Comment: The `-` initialised type coercion, causing them to be interpreted as numbers.

Comment: - operator is not there for string. So they are converted and hence you got -30